# Symfony bug with forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am experiencing the following form error in Symfony:

> Neither the property "email" nor one of the methods "email()", "getemail()"/"isemail()"/"hasemail()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

This is what my form looks like:

**My App\Form\LostPasswordType:**

```
namespace App\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use App\Entity\LostPassword;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class LostPasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function builder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction('/forgotpw')
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('mail', EmailType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label'    => false,
                'attr'     => [
                    'autofocus' => false,
                    'class' => 'span8',
                    'placeholder' => 'example@example.com'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Reset Password',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-green']
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOption(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => LostPassword::class]);
    }
}
```

And this is my controller code:

```
$formReset = $this->createForm(
    LostPasswordType::class,
    $forgotpass,
    array('csrf_protection' => false)
);
$formReset->handleRequest($request);
```

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error?

Comment: You added a property called 'mail' and are getting an error about 'email'.  Hmmm.

Comment: That is form type, means i've added in my Entity functions for getEmail and setEmail.

Comment: Then why call it 'mail'?

Comment: The name of the field doesn't matter. I was doing forms in the best practices. And if the error was because of that, i will get it on all pages including login too. But im experiencing only here. I think is related something to framework bug.

Comment: The odds are very tiny that it is a Symfony bug.  Why do you think the name of the field does not matter?  Humor me for a moment and change it to email in your form type and see what happens.

Comment: Man it was already, i was thinking the same before opened this discussion. Then it says again the same.
It's not in the field's name.

Comment: Ah.  Now I see what is going on.  There are some people who enjoy posting questions where the code in the question does not match the actual code.  Does make it challenging.  Much easier when your posted code matches your actual code but oh well.  Maybe someone else wants to play.

Comment: Man, you recently asked that name of the fields can make a problem? tell me how.

In html is that "name" attribute, now how it will make a problems. I changed the field in email and i have the same issue. Maybe it's in EmailType class something. I will try now to change to textType and will see.

Comment: @Cerad is right: you must have a mismatch between `forgotpass` (whatever it is) and `LostPasswordType`. Please, post the *actual* code of both classes so when can help you. Moreover I would like to highlight that you're not behaving with the right constructive attitude that we, as a community, embrace  and recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing the method function name in form builder, it was mistake there.